# Why is the constructor private in this Java DFS algorithm for finding cycles in graphs.

Tags: java, constructor, access-modifiers

This is code from my text book.

I don't see a situation where someone would want to access the variables in the constructor (DirectedCycle) outside the class, so why not let it have the default private modifier?

[image: code]

Comment: The constructor is not private. Furthermore if this is a textbook about algorithms, I wouldn't mind much about the OO-design. The source code in that case simply aims to *demonstrate* how to do something.

Comment: Constructor is `public`, `dfs()` method is `private` and is called from the constructor. All class members are `private`. Don't understand your question..

Comment: `private` is not the default access modifier. That's `package-private`, which allows access to other classes within the same package. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html